# can not upload pdf file in multipart form request

Tags: android, file, multipartform-data

I need to upload files using multipart form.

I can upload images from path below:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20160614-224624.png
```

However, when I try to upload a PDF file, it fails. PDF file path is :

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.docs/cache/projector/pdf.pdf
```

Can any one tell me why it is work with image and fail with pdf ??

This is my code :

```
try {
    MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(ForSaleConstants.EXTRA_FILE_UPLOADER, ForSaleNetworkManager.CHARACTER_SET);
    multipart.addFormField(ForSaleConstants.DEVICE_ID, deviceId);

    String uriString = extraFileUri.toString();
    Log.e("File_URI", uriString);
    uriString = Uri.decode(uriString);

    if (uriString.contains("file://")) {
        uriString = uriString.replace("file://", "");
        File uploadFile = new File(uriString);
        multipart.addFilePart(("file"), uploadFile);
    } else if (uriString.contains("content://")) {
        uriString = FileManager.getInstance().getRealPathFromImageUri(context, Uri.parse(uriString));
        File uploadFile = new File(uriString);
        multipart.addFilePart(("file"), uploadFile);
    } else {
        try {
            File uploadFile = new File(uriString);
            multipart.addFilePart(("file"), uploadFile);
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }


    List<String> response = multipart.finish();

    if(response != null && response.size() > 0) {

        mStopTime = System.nanoTime();
        PerformanceManager.getInstance().showCalculatedTime("uploadExtraFile [doInBackground]", mStartTime, mStopTime);

        JSONObject json = ForSaleNetworkManager.convertStringToJSONObject(response.get(0));
        BaseResponse response1 = new BaseResponse(json, null);
        return response1;

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    uiListener.onUploadExtraFileCompleted(null, AppError.DATA_ERROR);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your application package ?

### com.google.android.apps.docs

```
    /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.docs/cache/projector/pdf.pdf
```

If not you cannot access it because of sandboxing.

> Update

Each android application run in its own linux process hence you cannot access files in different application unless its stored in the common location. Like your image is. Hence you are not able to upload the pdf file

Comment: no I just download file from google chrome and choose it, and this is the path that I got.

Comment: but the problem still found while I move the file to the following path : /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/pdf.pdf

Comment: The server always give me error "incorrect file format",